# Redis Sentinel восстановление исходного мастера

Tags: redis

Я настроил репликами между master и двумя slave. Все работает. потом прочитал документ про sentinel и то как он может на автомате подменять отказавший master одним из slave переведя его в режим мастера и заставляя обновляться всех уже с него. Конфигурация минимальная, как в рекомендации, и все работает. Отключаешь master, одни из slave берет мгновенно его работу на себя. и так далее.
В итоге у меня один master, 2 slave и 3 sentinel(https://redis.io/topics/sentinel)
конфиг похож на этот.

sentinel monitor mymaster 127.0.0.1 6379 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds mymaster 100
sentinel failover-timeout mymaster 100
sentinel parallel-syncs mymaster 1

Моя проблема: если я опять включаю master, то данные на нем не обновляются (не синхронизируется с текущей группой и не передаются новые значения в эту группу). Фактически он становиться бесполезным. Почему? и как это решить?

Если проблема в конфигурации, могу выложить ее тут.

Comment: Что показывает `redis-cli info` до выключения мастера и после включения? Приложите эти логи и для самих редисов, и для сентинелей. И да, у вас там случайно партишны не настроены?

Comment: @Suvitruf нет не настроена еще не дорос объем данных до этого. К сожалению не успел посмотреть команду, так как обнаружил, что конфигурация для master была в чем-то отлична от slave (помимо настроек репликации). Скопировавшая еще раз правильный конфиг и протестировал. Теперь в конец файла всегда добавляется правильный адрес slaveof. Спасибо